# How can I set up ELK Stack to observe a Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am working on a Laravel project and would like to set up ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) Stack to monitor my application logs. I want to be able to analyze and visualize the logs in real-time to gain insights into the performance and behavior of my application.

Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide or a tutorial on how to set up ELK Stack to monitor a Laravel project? Specifically, I would like to know how to configure Logstash to collect and parse the Laravel logs, and how to create visualizations in Kibana to analyze the data.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: a quick search in google and SO returned plenty of helpful information. Are you facing a specific and different problem?

Comment: @glenacota I've found this one: https://fly.io/laravel-bytes/integrating-the-elastic-stack-elk-into-a-laravel-app-on-fly/ but it doesn't show anything about Logstash. When it comes to Laravel, I can go without Logstash?